# python error: can't assign to function call

Tags: python, python-2.7

This may be a stupid question, Why do i get this error?
when I chane int(r) into r, it makes TypeError"unsupported operand type(s) for - 'str' and 'int'"
I want to make the program that compare the YOURNUMBER with random number and repeat "n" times.
How can I solve this problem?

```
import random
r = raw_input("put YOURNUMBER")
while True: 
    n = raw_input("put repetition number")
    int(r)= int(r) - 1
    for x in range(10):
        x = random.randit()
    if int(r)!= 0:
        if int(n) > int(x):
            print "n > x"
        if float(n) == float(x):
            print "n = x"
        if float(n) < float(x):
            print "n < x"
    else:
        break
print "The end"
```

Comment: You get the error because you are attempting to subtract an `int` from a String.

Comment: omg It was a really easy thing. I didn't realize I don't put int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `r` to an integer before entering the while loop. Similarly convert `n` to an integer when it is input. Also it should be `random.randint()`, not `random.randit()`  - and it requires some arguments for the range of values:

```
import random
r = int(raw_input("put YOURNUMBER"))
while True: 
    n = int(raw_input("put repetition number"))
    r = r - 1
    for x in range(10):
        x = random.randint(1, 10)
    if r != 0:
        if int(n) > int(x):
            print "n > x"
        if float(n) == float(x):
            print "n = x"
        if float(n) < float(x):
            print "n < x"
    else:
        break
print "The end"
```

Comment: @CwsdfYasd Select it as the best answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

```
import random

r = raw_input("put YOURNUMBER: ")
r = int(r)


while True:
    n = raw_input("put repetition number: ")
    n = int(n)

    if n == 0:
        break

    for _ in xrange(n):
        x = random.randint(1, 10)

        if r > x:
            print "%s > %s" % (r, x)
        if r == x:
            print "%s = %s" % (r, x)
        if r < x:
            print "%s < %s" % (r, x)

print "The end"
```

Every variable has a type. Function `raw_input` returns a string, that's why `r` and `n` are strings firstly. Function `int()` converts variable into integer. After your converting into integer you don't need to use `int()` for `r` and `n` again